# nuxt.js build: Cannot read property 'renderRoute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, build, nuxt.js, build-error

I'm using laravel-nuxt.

When i'm trying to build the project for deployment i get this error:

```
 ERROR   /about                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    18:54:52  

TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderRoute' of undefined
    at Generator.generateRoute (C:\Users\myProj\node_modules\@nuxt\generator\dist\generator.js:222:42)
    at Promise.all.routes.splice.map (C:\Users\myProj\node_modules\@nuxt\generator\dist\generator.js:120:24
```

on all route i have in my "Pages" folder.

I have no clue on how to fix this, and I really appreciate all help I can get!

Tell me what more info you guys need to figure this one out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem today and went back to nuxt 2.9.0 by changing my
`package.json` file like this

```
// "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
"nuxt": "2.9.0",
```

after that I hit `npm install` again and nuxt seems to work again

Comment: laravel-nuxt creator here. I encountered this same error without using laravel-nuxt. You can track the issue here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6500

Answer (score 0):

This problem is cause by @nuxt/generator. 
The problem is being fixed in this pull request now: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/6529

While waiting for the pull request to be reviewed, here is my work around:

```
"nuxt": "2.9.2",
"@nuxt/generator": "2.9.2"
```

And removed `/node_modules` and `yarn` install dependencies again.
Now the build works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is now resolved you can update the Nuxt package

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/upgrading/